# C++ vector or Queue to build large Q in term of memory and speed

Tags: c++, performance, vector, queue

I am building a large queue of messages and using only PUSH and POP so which will be more efficient (vector or Queue) to maintain a large data with maximum speed

```
struct MQStruct {
    wchar_t *serviceName; 
    int durability; 
    int msgType; 
    int msgHeader; 
    wchar_t *msgId; 
    wchar_t *payload; 
    int payloadSize; 
    int ttl; 
    int priority;
}MQStructObj;

vector<MQStruct> MQvector;
queue<MQStruct> MSQ;

int SendMessage(wchar_t *serviceName, int durability, int msgType, int msgHeader, wchar_t *msgId, wchar_t *payload, int payloadSize, int ttl, int priority) {

MQStructObj.serviceName=serviceName;
MQStructObj.durability=durability;
MQStructObj.msgType=msgType;
MQStructObj.msgHeader=msgHeader;
MQStructObj.msgId=msgId;
MQStructObj.payload=payload;
MQStructObj.payloadSize=payloadSize;
MQStructObj.ttl=ttl;
MQStructObj.priority=priority;

    //Which one is better (Vector or Queue) in term of memory, speed and why

MSQ.push(MQStructObj);

    //OR

MQvector.push_back(MQStructObj);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Queue is an adaptor which uses one of the other containers underneath... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue

Comment: `std::vector` is not suitable at all for a queue, are you sure you are asking for this?

Comment: @Gorpik: yes, just wanted to make sure. thanku for answer btw :)

Comment: Which container depends on the characteristics you need - if you enqueue N items then all containers will hold N items (memory)... queue uses a Deque by default. Speed wise will depend on how "pop/push" actually works. Your best bet is to profile different structures - maybe using the default Deque is best for you? But it depends on your specific requirements

Comment: Make two programs, one using each method, and benchmark each. Compare results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `std::vector` you can not efficiently simulate a queue - you may only PUSH and POP from one side of the container. If you need to implement a message **queue** then use a queue, that's what it's meant for.

Answer (score 27):

There are many discussions regarding queue/vector/list on SO, you could search and reuse the resource. In short:

- Use `std::queue`: If you need fast insertion and deletion at both its beginning and
  its end;
- Use `std::vector`, if you need random access to elements
- When there are frequent insertions and deletions from the middle of
  the sequence you need `std::list`

**As you use only push/pop to the container, `std::queue` is the way instead of `std::vector` for sure.**

You can get more details from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Comment: In fact, `std::queue` (which uses an `std::deque` by default) is even better because it offers a more natural interface for OP's purposes and should have no performance penalty against a direct `std::deque`.

Comment: Thank you so much for detail explanation, I don't need insertion and deletion on both ends so with ref to your ans, std::queue is better choice for me

Comment: @Shahzad right. use std::queue instead, I'v updated my answer accordingly